# Flutter equivalent to curl --resolve

Tags: flutter, curl, https, localhost

I want make https request to ip address, but it should use domain name ssl certificate,
basically I want **curl --resolve** equivalent in flutter. or local DNS inside the app.
Working  curl command `curl --resolve example.com:443:192.168.1.55 https://example.com`

Answer (score 0):

To set custom DNS resolution for the request, use dart:io's HttpClient and make a custom instance with the desired configuration.

```dart
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:http/io_client.dart' as http;

Future<http.Response> resolve(String url, String domain, String ipAddress) async {
  // Create an HttpClient with the custom DNS resolution
  final httpClient = HttpClient()
    ..badCertificateCallback = ((X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true)
    ..connectionTimeout = const Duration(seconds: 10);

  // Add the custom IP address for the domain
  httpClient.findProxy = (uri) => 'PROXY $ipAddress:443';

  // Create an http.Client using the custom HttpClient
  final client = http.IOClient(httpClient);

  // Make the request
  final response = await client.get(Uri.parse(url), headers: {
    'Host': domain,
  });

  // Close the client to avoid resource leaks
  client.close();

  return response;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I am getting **Connection closed before full header was received** error